# Why "somebody stop me" instead of "somebody stops me" which is grammatically correct?

Tags: third-person, singular-subject-and-verb

The famous line of Jim Carrey in the move *The Mask*: "Somebody stop me!"

[image]

Grammatically, I believe it should be "somebody stops me" because somebody is third person singular.

So, why is it acceptable to say "somebody stop me"?

Comment: He's asking to be stopped.

Comment: If he'd seen Lt. Mitch Kellaway at that moment, would he have shouted "Mitch, stop me!" or "Mitch stops me!"? There needs to be a pause after 'Mitch' (hence the comma), while the run-on sfter 'somebody' sounds quite natural.

Comment: He is doing more than asking those around him to stop him. He is daring them: Go ahead, come here and stop me ... if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "stop" in "stop me" is an imperative. It could also be interpreted as an elided form of "[I dare] somebody [to] stop me!"

The imperative has two forms, both of which use the infinitive:

- First person (only plural): Let's **stop** me!
- Second person: [You] **stop** me!

We can demonstrate this is the infinitive form by using the verb "to be":

- First person (only plural): Let's **be** good!
- Second person: [You] **be** good!

So for the desired meaning it can never be "Somebody **stops** me!" because it's either an imperative or not the main verb, therefore using the infinitive in either case.

"Somebody **stops** me" is simple present or habitual:

> I try to go to the shops but somebody **stops** me. (simple present)
>
> Every time I try to go to the shops somebody **stops** me. (habitual)

Answer (score 4):

> Grammatically, I believe it should be "somebody stops me" because somebody is third person singular.

I think 'somebody' is not a 3rd person subject but a 2nd person subject since the sentence is directed to the listener.

Moreover, it's more like an imperative sentence than a declarative sentence, so the basic form 'stop' is correct.

Comment: Also, 'Somebody help me!'

Comment: 'Somebody help me' is possibly an imperative sentence, isn't it?

Comment: @RamPillai It's not just "possibly" one but definitely one.

Comment: @listeneva: Yes; hence 'help' is enough (not helps); which is what I meant to say.